# cast Timespan.Ticks to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to cast Timespan.Tick stored as Bigint in SQL Server to format
'00 d, 00 h, 00 m' as varchar in SQL Server.

I'm stuck. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_DateTimeFromTicks]  
(@tick BIGINT, @referenceDate DATETIME)  
RETURNS DATETIME  
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS  
begin  
return (select dateadd(ss,@tick / cast(10000000 as bigint),@referenceDate))  
end
```

Sample usage:

```
select dbo.[fun_DateTimeFromTicks](125000000000,'1900-01-01')
```

Since it returns a DateTime, you can format it as you want.